# set /p menu=type:ghost variable

Tags: batch-file

Here is my problem when I type a variable into the code below and hit enter the code works, but if I hit enter again it reads the same code even through the screen has been cleared.

```
:type
set /p menu=type:

    if /i "%menu%" == "go north" goto north
    if /i "%menu%" == "go south" goto south
    if /i "%menu%" == "go east" goto east
    if /i "%menu%" == "go west" goto west
    echo %name%, that command does not exist.
    pause
    cls
    goto play
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reset the variable `menu` or it will stay as defined :

```
:type
set menu=
set /p menu=type:

if /i "%menu%" == "go north" goto north
if /i "%menu%" == "go south" goto south
if /i "%menu%" == "go east" goto east
if /i "%menu%" == "go west" goto west
echo %name%, that command does not exist.
pause
cls
goto play
```